# Free SSH terminal emulator for Windows with a horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: windows, ssh, terminal, putty

Is there is SSH client for Windows that has a horizontal scrollbar?

i use PuTTy, and the lack of a horizontal scrollbar is driving me nuts.

Terminator requires extra external libraries to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

[Teraterm](http://sourceforge.jp/projects/ttssh2/) has comparibale feature set to Putty.  After you have installed, you will need to change the terminal settings.  You do this by the `Setup -> Terminal` menu.  Uncheck **Term size = win size** and then you can set the width and height manually.  The window will then give you a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: On the downside: if you turn off **Term size = win size** then the terminal no longer auto-scrolls. Also, dear god, Teraterm is ugly as sin!